# What is the kernel command line to disable bluetooth in /etc/default/grub?

Tags: kernel-modules, bluetooth

What is the kernel command line to completely disable bluetooth in /etc/default/grub? I don't have it, don't need it, don't want it, complete waste of resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Arch, Ubuntu/Debian family and the later RedHat/CentOS/Fedora systems, you blacklist the module by adding `bluetooth.blacklist=yes` at boot time.

If you're using RedHat 6 and it's derivatives you can use the `rdblacklist=bluetooth` boot option to blacklist a module (assuming the module is called `bluetooth` on these systems).